# General solution to offloading blocking function to executor in Tornado app

Tags: python, python-3.x, tornado, python-asyncio

I am trying to find a general solution for offloading blocking tasks to a `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

In the example below, I can achieve the desired non-blocking result in the `NonBlockingHandler` using Tornado's `run_on_executor` decorator.

In the `asyncify` decorator, I am trying to accomplish the same thing, but it blocks other calls.

Any ideas how to get the `asyncify` decorator to work correctly and not cause the decorated function to block?

**NOTE:** I am using Python 3.6.8 and Tornado 4.5.3

Here is the full working example:

```python
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import functools
import time

from tornado.concurrent import Future,  run_on_executor
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web


def asyncify(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        result = Future()

        def _run_on_executor(fn):
            @functools.wraps(fn)
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
                    return executor.submit(fn, *args, **kwargs)
            return wrapper

        @_run_on_executor
        def _func(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        def on_response(response):
           result.set_result(response.result())

        future = _func(*args, **kwargs)
        future.add_done_callback(on_response)

        return await result
    return wrapper


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write(f"Hello, {self.__class__.__name__}")


class AsyncifyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @asyncify
    def get(self):
        print("sleeping")
        time.sleep(5)
        self.write(f"Hello, {self.__class__.__name__}")


class NonBlockingHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)

    @run_on_executor
    def blocking(self):
        print("sleeping")
        time.sleep(5)
        self.write(f"Hello, {self.__class__.__name__}")

    async def get(self):
        result = Future()
        publish = self.blocking()
        publish.add_done_callback(
            lambda response: result.set_result(response.result())
        )
        return await result


def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
        (r"/asyncify", AsyncifyHandler),
        (r"/noblock", NonBlockingHandler),
    ], debug=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exiting a `with ThreadPoolExecutor` block waits (synchronously!) for all tasks on the executor to finish. You can't shut down an executor while the IOLoop is running; just make a global run and let it run forever.

Comment: I got it to work by changing the wrapper to:
    `executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1);`
    `return executor.submit(fn, *args, **kwargs)`